# How to marshal an ECC public or private key

Tags: json, go, cryptography

Hello i'am trying to unmarshal object that contain ECC public key 
but i go umarshaling error saying that can't unmarshal object properly.
i'am tring to do the followeing :

```
var privateKey *ecdsa.PrivateKey
var publicKey ecdsa.PublicKey
privateKey, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to generate ECDSA key: %s\n", err)
}
publicKey = privateKey.PublicKey

marshalledKey, err := json.Marshal(publicKey)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var unmarshalledKey ecdsa.PublicKey
err2 := json.Unmarshal(marshalledKey, &unmarshalledKey)
if err2 != nil {
    panic(err2)
}
```

and tthe error returned from (err2) is :

panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field PublicKey.Curve of type elliptic.Curve

and there is no way in either eliptoc or 509x function to umarshal and the curve value is alwayes null

Comment: It sounds like you have some code you're having trouble with. Please edit your question to include the exact error message, and the code you have that's producing the error - if possible as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: done and thank you

Comment: It is better to try and *binary encode* and *decode* the public key value. There are standards for storing EC public keys and if you store them that way any runtime should be able to read them back (if you specify how they are encoded anyway). If need arises, you can always serialize or marshal / unmarshal the resulting byte array. Unfortunately I'm not all that familiar with the two runtimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer finally and i will post it in case somone need it.
all we need is just to creat another struct, lets name it "retrieve" and declare the value it wil read from the unmarshal.
now the ECC public key contain 3 values "curve" and will append it as `json:"Curve"`, "Y" ans will append it as `json:"Y"` and we will do the same for "X"

and it will work like this :

```
type retrieve struct {
    CurveParams *elliptic.CurveParams `json:"Curve"`
    MyX         *big.Int              `json:"X"`
    MyY         *big.Int              `json:"Y"`
}

//UnmarshalECCPublicKey extract ECC public key from marshaled objects
func UnmarshalECCPublicKey(object []byte) (pub ecdsa.PublicKey) {
    var public ecdsa.PublicKey
    rt := new(retrieve)

    errmarsh := json.Unmarshal(object, &rt)
    if errmarsh != nil {
        fmt.Println("err at UnmarshalECCPublicKey()")
        panic(errmarsh)
    }

    public.Curve = rt.Key.CurveParams
    public.X = rt.Key.MyX
    public.Y = rt.Key.MyY
    mapstructure.Decode(public, &pub)

    fmt.Println("Unmarshalled ECC public key : ", pub)
    return
}
```

we will pass the the marshalled public key to UnmarshalECCPublicKey() and it will return the correct unmarshaled obj

so the coorect use will be :

```
var privateKey *ecdsa.PrivateKey
var publicKey ecdsa.PublicKey
privateKey, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to generate ECDSA key: %s\n", err)
}
publicKey = privateKey.PublicKey

marshalledKey, err := json.Marshal(publicKey)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var unmarshalledKey ecdsa.PublicKey
unmarshalledKey = UnmarshalECCPublicKey(marshalledKey)
```

and that should do it, u will get the ECC public unmarshalled successfully.